# How to change VIM underlines colors

Tags: vim

I'm an author of a VIM colorscheme ([danger.vim](https://raw.github.com/igorgue/dotvim/master/colors/danger.vim)) and I'd like to change some colors that I can barely see.

This is how it looks in Solarized:

[image]

This is how it *looks* in my theme:

[image]

As you can see, it's hard to see the *underlines* at `import sys`. I'd make them probably lighter blue, and bold.

I use the [Syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/) plugin to integrate with Pyflakes and JSLint mainly.

I also use [Flux](http://stereopsis.com/flux/), probably a reason why it's even harder to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like Syntastic shows *warnings* as *spell errors*, so all I had to do was to define:

```
SpellBad    word not recognized         |hl-SpellBad|
SpellCap    word not capitalised            |hl-SpellCap|
SpellRare   rare word               |hl-SpellRare|
SpellLocal  wrong spelling for selected region  |hl-SpellLocal|
```

In my colorscheme file.

Answer (score 5):

In your colorscheme file at:

```
hi Error   guifg=NONE guibg=NONE gui=undercurl ctermfg=white ctermbg=red cterm=NONE guisp=#FF6C60 " undercurl color
```

Change the part after `guisp` to the color you want.

i.e.

```
hi Error   guifg=NONE guibg=NONE gui=undercurl ctermfg=white ctermbg=red cterm=NONE guisp=#FFFFFF " undercurl color
```

will make the underlines white

edit:
You can make errors bold by change `gui=undercurl` to `gui=bold,undercurl`

Comment: Thanks, but Error was already red, this is for warnings, see my answer for more details.